# Error when opening multi-term: error in process filter: Invalid face: unspecified

Tags: multi-term

When I try to start `multi-term`, I these two errors which prevent the buffer from taking input:

`error in process filter: face-attribute: Invalid face: unspecified
error in process filter: Invalid face: unspecified`

I'm using Spacemacs, if that helps.

Comment: Please provide a lot more info - platform, Emacs version, and recipe to reproduce the problem, starting from `emacs -Q`.